# A p-Sylow subgroup of a subgroup is a p-sylow subgroup of the group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Is that true? If it is, then it is unprovable. I guess it isn't. The question is: how can I show it unequivocally? The definition my teacher gave us is:

> $P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ if $|P|=p^k$ with $p$ prime whereas $|G|=p^km$ and $(m,p)=1$.

How can I stick to this definition in my proof?

Comment: I gave you a counter example below. In fact, any $p$ group can be a counter example here. In those group the only $p$ Sylow groups are the group itself.

Comment: Yes but I can't seem to contradict it using the definition below... I can't place the variables :(

Comment: what is the problem? the unique $2$-Sylow subgroup of $C_2\times C_2$ is ifself. The unique $2$-subgroup of $C_2$ is itself. In particular, $C_2$ is not a $2$-Sylow of $C_2\times C_2$. In both $m=1$.

Comment: Is it a Cartesian product or the direct product? 
I mean, are the elements or the form (a,b)?

Comment: Think about your definition this way, a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is one that has size a prime power...that is also the biggest possible prime power dividing $|G|$. Then is it intuitive that this probably doesn't work?

Comment: No matter how you write it. Its the non-cyclic group of order $4$. As I said, any $p$ group of non-prime order is a counter example to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I used Z9xZ3 with Z9 as a 3-sylow subgroup(of itself). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
$$G=C_2\times C_2$$ 
with subgroup $C_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently no: take $G=\mathbf Z/p^n\mathbf Z$. As a $p$-group, it is the only p-Sylow subgroup of itself. Its subgroups are $H_k=p^k\mathbf Z/p^n\mathbf Z\simeq \mathbf Z/p^{n-k}\mathbf Z\enspace (k=0,\dots,n)\,\,$ and are their own p-Sylow subgroups.